# Spring Mongo Aggregation give a conversion error

Tags: spring, spring-data-mongodb

I'm trying to use Mongo aggregation but I receive an error that I don't understand.

This is my domain:

```
   @Document(collection = "tapes")
   public class Tape {

      @Id
      private String id;

      private String area;

      private Integer tape;

      private String tapeModel;
    
     // follow getters e setters
```

The mongo shell command and the output is the following:

```
> db.tapes.aggregate([{ $group: { _id: { "area":"$area"}, tapes: {$push: {tape: "$tape"}}}}  ])
{ "_id" : { "area" : "free" }, "tapes" : [ { "tape" : 1 }, { "tape" : 2 } ] }
{ "_id" : { "area" : "Qnap" }, "tapes" : [ { "tape" : 3 } ] }
```

The following is an attempt to re-create the aggregation in Spring:

```
AggregationOperation group = Aggregation.group("area").push("tape").as("tape");
Aggregation aggregation = Aggregation.newAggregation(group);
AggregationResults<Tape> results = mongoTemplate.aggregate(aggregation, "tapes", Tape.class);
//List<Tape> tapes = mongoTemplate.aggregate(aggregation, mongoTemplate.getCollectionName(Tape.class), Tape.class).getMappedResults();
List<Tape> tapes = results.getMappedResults();
System.out.println(tapes);
```

But I obtain the following error:

```
Cannot convert [3] of type class java.util.ArrayList into an instance of class java.lang.Integer! Implement a custom Converter<class java.util.ArrayList, class java.lang.Integer> and register it with the CustomConversions. Parent object was: it.unifi.cerm.cermadminspring.domain.Tape@2b84da07 -> null
org.springframework.data.mapping.MappingException: Cannot convert [3] of type class java.util.ArrayList into an instance of class java.lang.Integer! Implement a custom Converter<class java.util.ArrayList, class java.lang.Integer> and register it with the CustomConversions. Parent object was: it.unifi.cerm.cermadminspring.domain.Tape@2b84da07 -> null
```

I don't understand why, I searched for aggregation examples and all are more or less similar to mine.

Someone can help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, for making life easier, a more simplified aggregation can be used:

```
> db.tapes.aggregate([ {$group: {_id: "$area", tapes: {$push: "$tape"}}} ])
```

Which should yield:

```
{ "_id" : "free", "tapes" : [  1 , 2  ] }
{ "_id" : "Qnap", "tapes" : [  3  ] }
```

Which should be matched by a change to the Java `group` aggregation operation:
`AggregationOperation group = Aggregation.group("area").push("tape").as("tapes");`
Note that I've changed to plural: `as("tapes")`

Then, notice that you are actually returning a document which doesn't have the same structure as the one you've mapped in the `Tape` class.  That document contains two fields, the `String` `id` and a `List<Integer>` `tapes` fields.

This is the reason for the shorthand `group` aggregation I've suggested above, for making mapping easier:

```
public class TapesForArea {

    private String id; // which is the area

    private List<Integer> tapes;

    // getters, setters ...
}
```

You don't need to map this class using `spring-data-mongodb` annotations.

Finally, have the aggregation results return the right type:

```
AggregationResults<TapesForArea> results = 
    mongoTemplate.aggregate(aggregation, "tapes", TapesForArea.class);
List<TapesForArea> tapes = results.getMappedResults();
```

BTW, the error comes from the fact that you try to map the single item `tape` array `[ 3 ]` into `private Integer tape;` property of `Tape` class.